# Know what class instantiated a class

Tags: java, stack-trace

Basically, I'm creating an API. I have multiple endpoints, implemented as controllers. If an endpoint is called, it instantiates a parserclass, adds some options (like permitted parameters etc).

But now: If the parser fails, I want it to present a nice error, containing a link to the docs of the endpoint that actually failed.

I use b4j, which works on top of Java, so any relevant Java code should be easy to convert. In b4j, any endpoint is resembled by a class.

E.g.
I have a 'getPOIByCity' endpoint.

If a user calls this method, a city parameter is required. If he/she omits the parameter, I want the user to be greeted with an error containing:

> 1 required parameter missing: city
>
> See the documentation: http://www.link.to/doc/getPOIByCity

My first thought was to do some kind of stack tracing to know which class instantiated the parses class, but I cannot believe that is the way to do this.

C# has the slightly more elegant 'Caller information' attributes.

Any insights in how to do this?

Comment: That seems upside-down. I'd suggest having the parser throw a specific exception that the invoking class catches and turns into a useful error message, or else (if execution of the parser is not to be terminated by the first error) having the invoking class pass in a function object that does the error formatting.

Comment: I suggest making your question more clear, by giving better context to it. Don't assume that readers know what you're talking about. Write as if you're explaining the problem to a 16-year old. You'll see then, that the quality of your question will improve dramatically

Comment: @another-dave, That does makes much more sense indeed. It's been too long ago I did some serious programming. Shame I cannot accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another-dave already mentioned, it would make a lot more sense to delegate the exception to the calling class (the controller) and show the error from there.

But just to give an answer to your problem, you can use

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
String parentClass = stackTraceElements[2].getClassName();
Class cl = Class.forName(parentClass);
```

to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for telling both the good way to do it, and also the 'wrong' way, as people in the future may need that code for something.